# How to fix 'No such process' error from kill function on negation of pid

Tags: c, signals, posix

Attempting to write a signal handler for the SIGINT signal. I want a new SIGINT to be sent to a process group specified by a pid. (using the 'kill' function from signals.h).

The manpages for the kill function `man 2 kill` indicate that a negative pid will send a signal to the whole process group.

Previously I had this which only send the signal to the pid and it worked fine. The signal was sent and the process properly reacted.

```
void handle_sigint(int sig){
  pid_t pid = getprocesspid();
  if(kill(pid, sig) < 0){
    //Not taken
  }
}
```

However when I negate the pid, the kill function returns -1 and errors out with the "No such process" error.

```
void handle_sigint(int sig){
  pid_t pid = getprocesspid();
  if(kill(-pid, sig) < 0){
    //Errors out
  }
}
```

This is really odd to me. I can verifed that the pid is correct for the process. However, each time after I negate the pid the program crashes

Comment: Hey guenni_90, good point but I don't think so. There is indeed a `kill` command as a bash executable/built-in idk which. But the `signal.h` lib for c provides the `kill(pid_t pid, int sig)` function to send signals around. The man pages for this function can be viewed with `man 2 kill`.

Comment: The problem I believe is that you think you can negate *any* pid and it will be sent to the process group - but not all process ids are process group ids!

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tag, only add the tag for the language you're actually programming in. And that's even if a solution could be used in multiple languages.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Noted, fture posts will reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kill(-pid, sig)` will send the signal to the *process group* `pid`. `kill` will error with `ESRCH` if ([Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/kill.html)):

> `ESRCH`
>
> No process or **process group** can be found corresponding to that specified by `pid`.

Not all process IDs are process group IDs.

You can get the process group id of a process with [`pid_t getpgid(pid_t pid)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpgid.html), i.e.

```
pid_t pid = getprocesspid();
pid_t pgid = getpgid(pid);

if (pgid == -1) {
    // getpgid errored
}

if (kill(-pgid, sig) < 0){
    //Errors out
}
```

Comment: This is totally the correct answer! For my specific situation I needed to set the group id of the process through the `setpgid(pid_t pid, pid_t pgid)`. Thanks for the help!